# static Class in Constuructor

Tags: c#

I have two different project.

in first project I am creating a companent with classLibrary application and I getting .DLL file
after that  I am adding dll file to my toolbox in Second project(windows forms application).My problem is that second project (Windows application) have a static class and I have to use this static class in first project(my component).How can add this static class to my component class?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding" a static class? You don't need to "add" a class - you just use it.

Comment: What you mean by saying "add" ? Add it's reference to the WF prject, write it's name, use intellicense to add namespace, press (.) and get list of members..

Comment: Are you trying to use the winform static class in your DLL? If so, why dont you just keep the class in the DLL itself.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that there is a circular dependency here.  The static class is defined one assembly, but the other assembly wants to use it too.  That other assembly can't just reference the assembly with the class, because a reference in the opposite direction already exists.  That would make a circular dependency.

Comment: not add I want to use static class from Windows application.I dont wanna create static class for every component

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would say to define an interface for the class in the class library dll, but since the class is a static class, that won't work here.

Without knowing more about your situation, it seems that you will have to move that static class to a third project (another class library).  That way, both of your existing projects can reference that third dll and use the static class.

Comment: I am using this static class for database connection i dont wanna connect database for every component

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you try to work on both projects together in a solution, and try to reference each other you will get cross-reference error. Make an third library and expose your static class there. Reference third lib to other two project.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, if I understood you right, but it sounds you are getting ring dependencies, when first projects references second project which, in turn, references first project (for toolbox?).
So you would probably have to separate that static class of the second project into its own or at least another assembly/class library.